Defining quantum computer without reference to a classical computer
In the definition of an "efficient quantum computer", there is a uniformity condition that suggests to me that the notion of an efficient quantum computer is not independent of the notion of an efficient classical computer.
In particular, an efficient quantum computer is a uniform and polynomial size family of quantum circuits $(Q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. The uniformity here is P-uniformity, which means that the map $n \mapsto Q_n$ is computable in polynomial time on a classical computer.
Can one replace the uniformity condition with something else so that the definition of an efficient quantum computer does not depend on the notion of any sort of classical computer?

Sure, one can use e.g. quantum Turing machines. (Note that a classical circuit-based model has the same uniformity issue.)

For example, you can replace the statement "$n \mapsto Q_n$ is computable in polynomial time on a classical computer" with a statement such as "$n \mapsto Q_n$ is computable in polynomial time on a quantum Turing machine". Aaronson left this as an exercise in his lecture notes.

Makes sense, thanks!
